# Search Box Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, search-box

I want to make search box in google sheet.it should be work as slicer. Table of data need to filter using that search box.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTmjs.png)

I want to create search box as this excel search box using Google sheet.
[image]

Comment: I'd like to know this too, I know it would be possible to create GScript code that can work with a certain cell, and you can put a button next to it to activate the search function. But if it can be done more easier with some more build-in way, I'm interested!

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more.  Your image just shows a dropdown box, and I am not clear what you want it to do?  Sheets can probably do it.

Comment: i want Search Box for my Data table. It should work as slicer.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't use Excel. Would you mind explaining what it is/how it works?

Comment: I need Google sheet Search box.

Comment: Sorry I meant to ask if you could describe what the `search box` is, and how it works.

Comment: Please check above Image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I've done:

### Step 1: Define the filters

You already did it in the picture so I'm not explaining how it's done. Simply define the filter in the sheet.

### Step 2: Let's make the trigger

Before starting you need to note 2 things: the name of the sheet that has the search box, and the cell that does the search.

Then go to `Tools` > `Script editor` and paste the following code:

```js
const SHEET_NAME = 'Sheet1'
const SEARCH_CELLS = ['E10', 'E11', null]
function onEdit(e) {
  // Get edition range and sheet
  const { range } = e
  const sheet = range.getSheet()

  // If we are not in the correct cell, return
  if(sheet.getName() !== SHEET_NAME) return

  // Get the filter to be able to control it
  const filter = sheet.getFilter()

  // Number of columns to check
  const nCols = Math.min(SEARCH_CELLS.length, filter.getRange().getWidth())
  for (let i = 0; i < nCols; i++) {
    // Get the cell as A1 notation
    const cell = SEARCH_CELLS[i]
    
    // Ignore column if it has no cell with the value
    if (!cell) continue
  
    // Get the range used to search
    const searchRange = sheet.getRange(cell)
    const row = searchRange.getRow()
    const col = searchRange.getColumn()

    // If the search cell was edited set the value
    // This checks if the point (row, col) is in the box defined by the edited cells range
    if(range.getRow() <= row && range.getLastRow() >= row && range.getColumn() <= col && range.getLastColumn() >= col) {
      updateFilter(sheet, filter, i, searchRange.getValue())
    }
  }
}

function updateFilter(sheet, filter, columnOffset, value) {
  // Get the range of the values of the filter
  const filterRange = filter.getRange()
  
  // Get the column that we are filtering
  const column = filterRange.getColumn() + columnOffset

  if (value) {
    // Get all values except the selected value
    // Change this to change the logic of what to hide
    const hiddenValues = sheet.getRange(filterRange.getRow(), column, filterRange.getHeight(), 1)
      .getValues()
      .flat()
      .filter(v => v != value) // notice the non-strict equality

    // Set the criteria to hide them all
    const criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
      .setHiddenValues(hiddenValues)
      .build()
    filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(column, criteria)
  } else {
    // If there is not value, hide nothing
    filter.removeColumnFilterCriteria(column)
  }
}
```

Then change the constants on the top:

- The name of the sheet
- The list of all the search cell's A1 notation. The list should be in order, that is, the first cell is for the first column, the second cell for the second, and so on ans so forth. Set it to null if you don't want to search for that column.

I tried adding comments explaining step by step but feel free to ask if something is not clear or confusing.

### (Optional) Step 3: Add a dropdown the the search cell

If you want a drop down on the search cell that autocompletes and allows you to select it, do this (simple) step.

Select the search cell and right click it. Go to `Data validation`. In `Criteria` select `List from range` and add the range of all the values of the first column of the filter. Click `Save` and you did it.

### References

- [Simple triggers (Google Apps Script guide)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Edit trigger (Google Apps Script guide)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)
- [Class Filter (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter)
- [Class FilterCriteriaBuilder (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria-builder)
- [Class Range (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [Class Sheet (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)

Comment: i have some problem. can we change the filter column. like multiple  column filter option.

Comment: You can, actually. `setColumnFilterCriteria` first parameter is what column it is. Right now it's always the first column of the filter but feel free to add an offset or add logic to change which one it changes. Note that you will also need to change the column of `hiddenValues`.

Comment: Can you give some Example.?

Comment: If you tell me what column you'd like I can edit the answer. Or is it all of them?

Comment: I tried separate filters for each column. but works only one filter.

Comment: So basically you have multiple cells with the values to search? Should it be inclusive or exclusive?

Comment: yes. Exclusive.one search cell for one column

Comment: So basically you want to show any row where the filter is the same, right?

Comment: No I need filter for every column.

Answer (score 0):

here is a mockup https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/139PfSbmEEGt-1kXZAO5mdBJ73vhnliNXNL51R7T1wOI/edit?usp=sharing

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet()
  var cel = e.source.getActiveRange();
  var crit = [];
  var count = 0;
  if (cel.getRow()==1){
    try{
      sh.getFilter().remove();
    }
    catch(e){
    }
    for (var col=1;col<=sh.getLastColumn();col++){
      if (!sh.getRange(1,col).getValue() && sh.getRange(2,col).getValue() != ''){
        crit.push([sh.getRange(2,col).getValue()])
        count++
      }
    }
  }
  if (count != 0){
    var filter = sh.getRange('A4:J').createFilter();
      var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
        .setHiddenValues(crit)
        .build();
    filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(1, criteria);
  }
};
```

In A2 :

```
=transpose(unique(A5:A))
```

could probably be improved !
[image]

Comment: can you make when text type auto filter table

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you mean and expect, sorry.